# Visual studio unit testing "Start Debugging" starts all tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

Visual studio unit testing starts all tests when I use "Start Debugging" from Debug menu, instead just ones selected in Test List editor or Test results window. It's really annoying since I use shortcut to start projects not only while testing, and number of times I just hit that key automatically and VS starts all tests instead just one or two that I am currently debugging.

Can this be changed to just run selected tests in Test List Editor ?

UPDATE : I am aware of start commands under Test menu, but problem is that that shortcut is "hardcoded" in my brain and I use it every day number of times while debugging winforms and ASP.NET projects, and in unit test case it starts all tests

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem but I'm not using Keyboard Shortcut.  Within my test program (eg, test.cs), I have multiple test cases (multiple [FACT]).  on the Test Explorer, I run/debug only a particular test case, yet the code coverage (green lines) shows green for all the test cases.  Is this the expected behaviour ?  Or is there a setting that can show only the coverage for the particular test case ?  Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under Tools->Options, go to the Environment->Keyboard screen, then select the task you want to run when you press [F5]. Click in the "Press shortcut keys:" box (or press [Alt]+P), and then press [F5]. You'll see that it tells you that [F5] is currently used by Debug.Start. Click on the Assign button (or press [Alt]+S) to change [F5] to be what you want it to be. To restore the original functionality, repeat the above process but with Debug.Start as the item you're assigning the shortcut key to. (Or click on the Reset button if there's nothing else you want to preserve.)

Comment: hm, that would require changing shortcuts when switching between "normal" projects and unit test project. But maybe I can automate this ...

Comment: I'm pretty sure the keyboard bindings can differ between workspaces, so one option is to set up different workspaces for normal projects and unit test projects, if that makes sense for your workflow.

Comment: I'm facing a similar problem but I'm not using Keyboard Shortcut. Within my test program (eg, test.cs), I have multiple test cases (multiple [FACT]). on the Test Explorer, I run/debug only a particular test case, yet the code coverage (green lines) shows green for all the test cases. Is this the expected behaviour ? Or is there a setting that can show only the coverage for the particular test case ? Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

There are various options to run subsets (or all) tests under the debugger (or not debugging) under the Test menu. Further options are available on the Test View and Test Results tool windows.

The tool window specific commands include running selected tests.

Comment: I am aware of that, but problem is that I automatically press F5 (former Delphi user) to start debugging and all test starts to execute, will update my question

Comment: @Antonio I do that as well... you can of course always change the key mapping.