# Shortcut to reset current unit test when debugging

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I accidentally stepped over my breakpoint when debugging a single unit test in Visual Studio 2013.  I had to click "Stop Debugging"and then right-click over the test method and click "Debug Tests" to start over.

Is there a shortcut to re-run the CURRENT unit test that I'm stepping in?  Or shortcut to run "last test?"

Comment: possible duplicate of [Visual studio unit testing "Start Debugging" starts all tests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678455/visual-studio-unit-testing-start-debugging-starts-all-tests)

Comment: @Niang, not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6678455/visual-studio-unit-testing-start-debugging-starts-all-tests